# Изменение атрибутов терминала и sudo

Tags: linux, c, bash, консоль, sudo

Всем привет.
Я поддерживаю (+исправляю, допиливаю в меру возможностей и знаний) одно приложение, написанное на С под linux. После запуска приложения программа в риалтайме выводит результат работы, пока ее не остановят или пока не закончится указанный интервал времени работы программы. Поэтому я захотел отключить пользовательский ввод после запуска программы поменяв атрибут [ECHO](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/termios.3.html) у терминала и при выходе из приложения вернуть атрибуты назад. Все работает, все хорошо, но однажды запустив свое приложение под sudo под приложением [timeout](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-timeout/) я получил полное зависание программы, запустить под dbg с "sudo" у меня не получилось. Еще это может быть связано с переменными окружения... Написал отдельный исходничек, который показывает наличие проблемы:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct termios orig_termios;

void disableRawMode() {
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &orig_termios);
    printf("Term attributes restored\n");
}

void enableRawMode() {
    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &orig_termios);

    struct termios new_termios;

    memcpy(&new_termios, &orig_termios, sizeof(new_termios));
    new_termios.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &new_termios);

//
    if (new_termios.c_iflag & BRKINT)
      puts("BRKINT is set");
    else
      puts("BRKINT is not set");
    if (new_termios.c_cflag & PARODD)
      puts("Odd parity is used");
    else
      puts("Even parity is used");
    if (new_termios.c_lflag & ECHO)
      puts("ECHO is set");
    else
      puts("ECHO is not set");
//
}

int main(void)
{
    enableRawMode();
    if(atexit(disableRawMode)) printf("Error in atexit().\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Вот результаты запуска с/без sudo и т.д.

```
$ ./atexit_test 
BRKINT is set
Even parity is used
ECHO is not set
Term attributes restored

$ timeout 3s ./atexit_test 
BRKINT is set
Even parity is used
ECHO is not set
Term attributes restored

$ sudo su -p - root bash -c "timeout 3s /home/programer/media/atexit_test/atexit_test"
BRKINT is set
Even parity is used
ECHO is not set
Term attributes restored

$ sudo timeout 3s ./atexit_test
$
$ sudo timeout 3s ./atexit_test; echo $?
124
```

124 код возврата означает, что приложение не успело завершить свою работу за указанное время и приложению ушел kill 15 (TERM).

Так как под dbg запустить не вышло, то я пошел самым тупым способом, повставлял printf после каждой строки, обнаружил таким образом, что зависон получаю при выполнении:

```
tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &new_termios);
```

Окей, по ману если вызов команды неуспешен, получаем код возврата -1, если все ок - 0, все как везде, проверяем, что вернет errno:

```
if (tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &new_termios) == -1) {
        int errsv = errno;
        printf("%d",errsv);
    }
```

Но я ничего не получил, значит до проверки кода возврата tcsetattr не дошло...
Готов выслушать варианты решения или хотя бы локализации проблемы.

Comment: *отключить пользовательский ввод после запуска программы поменяв атрибут ECHO у терминала* — в огороде растение семейства адоксовых, а в столице полян брат одного из родителей. // по поводу поведения — явно наблюдается конфликт между манипуляциями с pty, прозвоидимыми всеми тремя программами: sudo, timeout и atexit_test.

Comment: если привязать gdb к процессу, то он постоянно долбится сигналом `SIGTTOU`, который приводит по-умолчанию к остановке...

Comment: А вы вообще понимаете, что вы делаете в приведенной строке? Flush на стандартный ввод — это как?

Comment: @0andriy если вы о **TCSAFLUSH**, так это всего лишь параметр, когда применить новые атрибуты.
`TCSAFLUSH
              the change occurs after all output written to the object
              referred by fd has been transmitted, and all input that has
              been received but not read will be discarded before the change
              is made.`
Если вы об **~ECHO**, то это соответственно отключение:
`ECHO   Echo input characters.`

Comment: Хорошо :) Вот тут есть статейка: https://viewsourcecode.org/snaptoken/kilo/02.enteringRawMode.html, при беглом взгляде ничего особенного не заметил. Возможно вы внимательнее почитаете и найдёте что-то полезное

Comment: @0andriy не поверите, именно из этой статьи я и брал примеры как и что юзать) Перечитаю еще раз, может где написано мелким шрифтом о возможных проблемах)

Answer (score 1):

Командой

```
sudo su -p - root bash -c "timeout 3s /home/programer/media/atexit_test/atexit_test"
```

вы запускаете полноценное окружение для выполняемой команды. поэтому И все отключения актуальны

а при выполнении

```
sudo timeout 3s ./atexit_test
```

пользовательское окружение не запускается. поэтому нечего отключать. скорее всего тут и происходит зависание. в итоге приложение убивается по таймауту  - 124

Посмотрите в сторону настроек sudo : SETENV и requiretty

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поиграть ключами sudo (-i, -s) вместо конструкции sudo su